# Unable to make cypress type in Google slides even though it's able to select the correct element

Tags: automation, cypress, google-slides

I'm trying to automate something in Google slides and able to do everything except type something.

For example, I want to type in speaker notes which are at the bottom of slides:

```
cy.get('#speakernotes-workspace').type('aaa')
```

It's able to select the correct element and `.type()` command passes too.

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

Only thing is the value is not being entered/typed. And it's not just speaker notes, I'm unable to type anywhere in Google slides through cypress. I've tried other possible methods like `{force: true}` or changing browsers but none works.